# Type coersion in javascript

Tags: javascript

What will be the output of the of following code:

```
console.log({}.valueOf()+15);//Output:[object Object]15
```

Will the return value from the *.valueOf()* method be string in the above code or is simply an object since *.toString()* will result in same but with this method returned value will be string anyhow.I just wanted to know what will be the type of the value the *.valueOf()* returns in above code.If return value is a string ,for what other object will *valueOf()* method returns string value except for **[new String("abc")]**

Comment: Who wants to close this post????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.valueOf()` of a plain object will be the same object. *(This is **NOT** the same as its `.toString()` method.)*

```
var o = {};

typeof o.valueOf(); // "object"

o === o.valueOf(); // true
```

The `+` operator sees that you're not using a number for the first operand, so instead of addition, it does string concatenation and calls the `.toString()` value of both of its operands.

That's why you get `[object Object]15`.

---

You can test this by changing the `toString()` output.

```
var o = {};
o.toString = function() { return "foobar" }

o.toString(); // "foobar"

o + 15;           // "foobar15"
o.valueOf() + 15; // "foobar15"
```

Comment: the valueOf() method returns plain object which is a string

Comment: @Maizere: No, the `.valueOf()` object returns a plain object which is *not* a string. It's just the same object. The `+` operator returns a string for reasons that I explained in my answer below the first code example.

Comment: plz see the comment in the Klink post above

Comment: @Maizere: Kolink's answer and comment is wrong. The `.valueOf()` is not the same as the `.toString()`, and does not return a string.

Comment: @scram This `o === o.valueOf();` may not always be true. Implementation specific according to ECMA-262.

Comment: @c-smile: Fair enough, but do you know of an implementation that doesn't return the object?

Answer (score 3):

`valueOf` returns a primitive value. Exactly what type of primitive value depends on the object.

To demonstrate:

```
typeof Number(0).valueOf(); // number
typeof Boolean(0).valueOf(); // boolean
```

The point is that, whatever it returns, it is a primitive value. `toString`, on the other hand, always returns a string.

In the case of `{}`, there is no `valueOf` method other than the root `Object.prototype.valueOf`, which is identical to `Object.prototype.toString`, returning a string of the form `[object Constructor]`. Which being a string results in concatenation with `15`.

Comment: but i m adding with a number

Comment: will number also gets coerced to String

Comment: Yes, because the first operand to `+` is a string in this case. If it were a number, you would be adding it.

Comment: Now i have started to know about type casting in javascript

Comment: last question for what other object will valueOf() method returns string

Comment: Date, for one. I can't be bothered to look for a list, in all honesty.

Comment: @Kolink According to 15.2.4.4 chapter in ECMA-script specification `Object.prototype.valueOf` returns object so it is not anyhow identical to `Object.prototype.toString`

Answer (score 0):

To get the type of an object in JS, you can use the **typeof** function:

```
typeof({}) // outputs 'object'
typeof({}.valueOf()) // outputs 'object'
typeof({}.valueOf()+15) // outputs 'string'
```

This indicates that the value coercion is taking place when trying to "add" 15, which instead is interpreted as string concatenation.